# Find largest file inside of tarball

Tags: python, gzip, tar

I have a massive gzipped tarball with 13000 files. How do I extract only the largest file inside of that from within a Python program?

I have tried reading through the tarball and checking the length each file extracted, but this is taking far too long. Is there any more optimized way to do this?

Original code (Added for the sake of completeness of this question, even though an answer was chosen):

```
from tarfile import TarFile
archive = TarFile(filename)
members = archive.getmembers()
sizes = []
for member in members:
    sizes.append(member.size)
largest = max(sizes)
largest_info = sizes.index(largest)
print(largest_info.name)
```

Comment: How do you expect to find the largest file without looking at all files in the tarball?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/tarfile.html)?

```
import tarfile
archive = tarfile.TarFile('/path/to/my/tarfile.tar')
max_size = 0
max_name = None
for file in archive.getmembers():
    if file.size > max_size:
        max_size = file.size
        max_name = file.name

print(max_size)
print(max_name)
```

Comment: wouldn't the builtin `max` function be better?  `max(archive.getmembers(), key=operator.itemgetter('size'))`

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: 'TarInfo' object is not subscriptable` when I run that.

Comment: `max(archive.getmembers(), key=operator.attrgetter('size'))` seems to work fine.

Comment: There's a colon missing after the `if` statement in this answer. Just a tiny error though.

Comment: @SimeonVisser -- Oops, should have been `attrgetter`

Answer (score 2):

The answer is you have to look through all the archive to find out biggest member. That is because [TAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29) file was designed for type archiving, and hence has no Table of Contents (TOC):

> The possible reason for not using a centralized location of information is that tar was originally meant for tapes, which are bad at random access anyway: if the Table Of Contents (TOC) were at the start of the archive, creating it would mean to first calculate all the positions of all files, which needs doubled work, a big cache, or rewinding the tape after writing everything to write the TOC

Simeon Visser provided you with working code.